# JAQL Cast int to string

Tags: jjaql

I am newbie to jaql, not of lot of documentation is found. Does jaql support inbuilt casting. Or java udf need to be written for casting. I basically want to convert int to string.

Answer (score 1):

try this:
jaql> serialize(500);
"500"